# Android Using Services , newbie's curiosity

Tags: android, service

I want to know some basic, practical, things about Services, that are not explicitly mentioned in the Android Developers reference pages.

1. How can I call a service from another app, that has not even started?
2. How do I query which services are provided by other applications?
3. Are services allowed to use UI methods? (the documentation says they are specifically meant not to have UI to the user, but their example has a Toast in it)
4. Are services re-entrant? (if two apps call the same service, will they be 'serviced' at the same time without messing with any local variable)
5. Are services the way plug-ins are made?
6. Can I use a service to extend the functionality of my already installed app? (i.e. can I 'install' just a service
7. Can services launch normal activities? Can they cause their clients to finish?

Comment: Actually, opening 7 questions is much better. This will get closed.

Comment: @amigableclarkkant Why is that?

Comment: http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/30/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-3-of-n/

Comment: With all the respect to Oded, it's his opinion. I think there is a background context connection between the questions. I am pretty sure that If I split them, I will immediately get negative votes for some of them, because the reader will not understand the context in which I am asking them.

Comment: I do agree though that I might get fewer responses. but chances are that that someone out there will post a link to a good blog or tutorial that addresses all these issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I call a service from another app, that has not even started?

Services like Activities are started through use of the `Intent` system. You can start a service using the `startService(intent);` method. This crosses application boundaries as long as the service is properly configured to answer intents from outside of it's own sandbox.

> How do I query which services are provided by other applications?

Documentation. I can't imagine a situation where you would want to interrogate an app for it's services **without** the documentation as you wouldn't know what to pass in order to get the service to perform correctly.

> Are services allowed to use UI methods? (the documentation says they are specifically meant not to have UI to the user, but their example has a Toast in it)

Services have access to the application context (and therefore can post `Toast`s or start `Activities` of their own). They may also have visibility of the app running in the same sandbox, this means that by means of handlers they can change the UI of the running Activity directly. By their nature however `Services` are not designed to interface with the UI even though it's possible.

> Are services re-entrant? (if two apps call the same service, will they be 'serviced' at the same time without messing with any local variable)

Services can be started with different flags (and can be programmed differently) to allow them to service received `Intents` in an asynchronous way or to queue the `Intents` to be performed serially. You can find more about this (and the rest of your question [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html))

> Are services the way plug-ins are made?

Plugins?

> Can I use a service to extend the functionality of my already installed app? (i.e. can I 'install' just a service

You can install a service as a seperate app which can catch `startService()` calls it's making if it isn't using a named `Intent`. This service would be in a different sandbox however and wouldn't have access to the running app's variables/state.

> Can services launch normal activities? Can they cause their clients to finish?

Yes, if the Service is running in the same sandbox they can have visibility of the App running alongside it. It can use `startActivity()` as it has access to application context and it can call static methods inside of the app (which could contain static access to the `Activity`).

Comment: Great! Only one doubt remains, regarding question 1. It is not clear if the other application, the one providing the service, is started automatically when I call the service, or it must be started already.

Comment: `startService(intent)` will start a stopped service, or will delivery the intent to an already started service. As a client you generally don't need to know if a Service is already running or not.

Comment: You said "As a client you generally don't need to know if a Service is already running or not." this meaning I can count on the service being launched anyway? Or will I get some RemoteException if it cannot be launched? This is a delicate point I think, if I want to rely on a service doing some work for me.

Comment: @ilomambo Remember, the service often runs in your calling threads context, if I read the Android docs correctly.

Comment: If the service **isn't** running that act of you passing an it will start it and handle your request. If it **is** started, it will still handle your request. Either way you're request will be handled so you don't need to know whether a service is running or not before you send your intent.